# What is the use of using count(1) = 1 when select statement have distinct keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the use of using count(1) = 1 when select statement have distinct keyword and only have a single column?

The query looks like:

```
select distinct (col1) 
FROM tab1
    where   creat_dt_tm >= sysdate - 1/24/60*30  and condition2 = "xyz" 
    group by col1,sys 
    having count(1) =1
```

What is the use of sys here in the group by clause?

What is the use of having count (1)  = 1 when we have distinct applied on the select statement?

I am not sure if I understand the logic in this.

Comment: Only you currently have access to any data which you can run this query against. In general though, all parts of that query are doing something, none appear redundant. If you're not able to provide some table definitions and sample data, you could at least try removing parts of the query and see how the results change.

Comment: Just in passing, the SQL expression for counting rows is `count(*)`, not `count(1)`. They both work, but the second one is nonstandard and the parser silently converts it to `count(*)`, so I am curious why you would not use the standard expression in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your table so I'll illustrate it on Scott's `emp` sample table.

This is its contents:

```
SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
        10       7934 MILLER     CLERK
        10       7782 CLARK      MANAGER
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT
        20       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20       7902 FORD       ANALYST
        20       7876 ADAMS      CLERK
        20       7369 SMITH      CLERK
        20       7566 JONES      MANAGER
        30       7900 JAMES      CLERK
        30       7698 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30       7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30       7521 WARD       SALESMAN
        30       7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30       7844 TURNER     SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Starting query might look like this: count combinations of `deptno` and `job` column:

```
SQL> select deptno, job,         --> all non-aggregated columns ...
  2         count(*)
  3  from emp
  4  group by deptno, job        --> ... must be part of the GROUP BY clause
  5  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB         COUNT(*)
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK              1
        10 MANAGER            1
        10 PRESIDENT          1
        20 ANALYST            2
        20 CLERK              2
        20 MANAGER            1
        30 CLERK              1
        30 MANAGER            1
        30 SALESMAN           4

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Your query now wants to return only rows whose count is equal to 1, so - let's add the `having` clause:

```
SQL> select deptno, job, count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job
  4  having count(*) = 1
  5  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB         COUNT(*)
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK              1
        10 MANAGER            1
        10 PRESIDENT          1
        20 MANAGER            1
        30 CLERK              1
        30 MANAGER            1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Query author decided not to display all columns, but only one of them; in my example, it'll be the `job` column (`group by` remains as it was):

```
SQL> select job
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job
  4  having count(*) = 1
  5  order by job;

JOB
---------
CLERK
CLERK
MANAGER
MANAGER
MANAGER
PRESIDENT

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Apparently, there are **duplicates**, hence `distinct` keyword **along** with `group by` clause:

```
SQL> select distinct job
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job
  4  having count(*) = 1
  5  order by job;

JOB
---------
CLERK
MANAGER
PRESIDENT

SQL>
```